# Are using conditional statements in frame counts proper coding?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

for example:

```
if (enemy.hit.currentFrame == enemy.hit.totalFrames) { //enemy hit animation end
    health -= enemy.damage;
}
```

Because I was wondering if it is possible that my game might lag causing it to skip the frame rendering the code useless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be save, Flash does not skip frames. If the application is lagging and rendering takes too long, the *frame rate* will drop instead of skipping frames.